# IOS 8 XCode 6 beta 4 exception when calling addObject in a game

Tags: iphone, xcode, swift, ios8

I'm following this tutorial [Tutorial space game](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=CpIoHPUyu8s), and I'm getting this: Thread 1: BAD_EXEC_INSTRUCTION(code=EXC_I386_INVOP,subcode=0x0). Everything freezes after, the first parts are ok I see the ship and the background, but when the enemies are supposed to come out the exception is thrown. The code is the following:

```
func addAlien() {

    var alien: SKSpriteNode = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "alien")
    alien.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(rectangleOfSize: alien.size)
    alien.physicsBody.dynamic = true
    alien.physicsBody.categoryBitMask = alienCategory
    alien.physicsBody.contactTestBitMask = photonTorpedoCategory
    alien.physicsBody.collisionBitMask = 0


    let minX = alien.size.width/2
    let maxX = self.frame.size.width - alien.size.width/2
    let rangeX = maxX - minX
    var position:CGFloat = CGFloat(Int(arc4random())) % CGFloat(rangeX) + CGFloat(minX)

    alien.position = CGPointMake(position, self.frame.size.height + alien.size.height)

    self.addChild(alien)

    let minDuration = 2
    let maxDuration = 4
    let rangeOfDuration = maxDuration - minDuration
    var duration = Int(arc4random()) % Int(rangeOfDuration) + Int(minDuration)


    var actionArray: NSMutableArray = NSMutableArray()




    actionArray.addObject(SKAction.moveTo(CGPointMake(position, -alien.size.height), duration: NSTimeInterval(duration)))  <------- Exception in this line
    actionArray.addObject(SKAction.removeFromParent())

    alien.runAction(SKAction.sequence(actionArray))
    //alien.runAction(SKAction.sequence(actionArray))

}
```

And I do not know what is wrong, the same was in another tutorial game. The function addAlien() is being called from:

```
func updateWithTimeSinceLastUpdate(timeSinceLastUpdate: CFTimeInterval) {

    lastYieldInterval += timeSinceLastUpdate
    if lastYieldInterval > 1 {
        lastYieldInterval = 0
        addAlien()

    }
}
```

Any help? Thanks.

EDIT: What XCode looks like.[image: XCode trace]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same issue with this tutorial.

I've fixed that exception modifying the duration using this code:

```
var duration = UInt32(arc4random()) % UInt32(rangeDuration) + UInt32(maxDuration)
```